# Clarification of a theorem from Chang's Methods in Nonlinear Analysis

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

The following theorem is taken from Chang's *Methods in Nonlinear Analysis*. It has a complete proof; however, I have some trouble understanding it (for example, I don't see what $K(f_{\sigma_i})$ means).

Could you help me get a clearer picture of this proof?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with this, but I was interested in this book; may I ask you what background knowledge is assumed on the part of the reader?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this book or its notation, but it appears $K(f_{\sigma_i})$ is the set of critical points of $f_{\sigma_i}$.

Comment: Sorry but know i have an other problem in a different subject so i can't see this post at this moment but thank you